# Jenkins default plugins are not available

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I tried to install plugins from jenkins web interface and using command line as well. I am failed on both:

1. After installing jenkins-1.429-1.1.noarch.rpm, when I go to manage plugins and search in available plugins like phpcpd:  pdepend: phpcs:phpdoc:phploc:  but those plugins are not available in the list. So strange.

   When I try to create build , I get error like http://pastie.org/2516863
2. On the top of that I manually try to install the plugins with command 
   java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 install-plugin checkstyle

, but unfortunately, I get error like
  Failed to authenticate with your SSH keys. Proceeding with anonymous access
  Installing checkstyle from update center

Can somebody suggest me why I am missing default plugins in jenkins and also why I am getting such ssh authentication error from command line.

I am looking forward to solve this issue sooner!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Those php related plugins don't come with jenkins, we need to install them manually. In case of redhat, I followed following process to install the plugins:

yum search plugin_name
yum install plugin name

how to install phpunit? it is different from previous method:
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit